# How do I check if Bcrypt password is correct?

Tags: php, laravel, bcrypt

I was using md5 to hash my passwords but learned that using bcrypt was more secure.

When using md5, it was easy to check whether a password entered in a form was correct. I simply done

```
if(md5($request->password) == $user->password)
   //Login or whatever
```

So how do I do this using bcrypt? I tried

```
if(bcrypt($request->password) == $user->password)
```

But that isn't working.

Comment: See [`password_hash()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php).

Comment: Also note, in your example, you're hashing the value from the database and comparing it to what the user typed. That's backwards -- you want to hash the value the user typed and compare it to the database.

Comment: Oh yes I see, just a typo. Edited.

Answer (score 4):

Use the [`attempt()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication#authenticating-users) method:

```
if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password]))
```

> The `attempt` method accepts an array of key/value pairs as its first argument. The values in the array will be used to find the user in your database table.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication#authenticating-users

Under the hood `attempt()` uses [`password_verify()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) method to check password.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the `check` method of the `Hash` Facade

```
if (Hash::check($request->password, $user->password)) {
    // The passwords match...
}
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/hashing#basic-usage